# CORS issue with jquery and cookies for subdomains

Tags: jquery, wordpress, cors

I'm running 2 sites on my local machine. (names configured via hosts file).

- cf2.localhost.net (laravel)
- cf2wp.localhost.net (wordpress)

When a user logs in to wordpress they get cookies from .localhost.net and when they load a page on the laravel site they receive this cookie data too.

When I try and do a jquery ajax request however the cookies aren't sent

Using chrome tools I've verified that:

- requesting http://cf2.localhost.net/home sends the wordpress cookies to the server
- the cors preflight is returned ok with

  ```
  Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
  Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Authorization, Content-Type
  Access-Control-Allow-Methods:OPTIONS, GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE
  Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://cf2.localhost.net
  Access-Control-Expose-Headers:X-WP-Total, X-WP-TotalPages
  Connection:Keep-Alive
  Content-Length:5166
  Content-Type:application/json; charset=UTF-8
  Date:Thu, 25 May 2017 06:30:36 GMT
  Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=100
  Link:<http://cf2wp.localhost.net/wp-json/>; rel="https://api.w.org/"
  Server:Apache/2.4.25 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2j PHP/7.1.1
  Vary:Origin
  X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff
  X-Powered-By:PHP/7.1.1
  X-Robots-Tag:noindex
  ```
- But the request that goes out next doesn't have the wordpress cookies set. It only has the encrypted laravel ones from cf2.localhost.net

  ```
  Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
  Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
  Accept-Language:en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
  Connection:keep-alive
  Content-Length:27
  Content-Type:application/json; charset=UTF-8
  Cookie:jenkins-timestamper-offset=-28800000; olfsk=olfsk19949676680174977; hblid=HFZEjdNeyuKRupkV3m39N0H8REA26ar9; _ga=GA1.1.1566562504.1495496019; io=qjc8cwjKxij4G9ggAAAA
  Host:localhost
  Origin:http://cf2.localhost.net
  Referer:http://cf2.localhost.net/home
  User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36
  ```

Any idea what is going on?

Comment: What domain have you specified on the cookie? You'll need to set `domain=localhost.net` for it to be available on both subdomains

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - .localhost.net. This cookie does go to the laravel server when we request the page. Just not when I do the ajax call

Answer (score 0):

In cross-site request, browser will not send credentials by default. You need to explicitly set the following attribute:

`request.withCredentials = true`